# Issue with running PDF.JS

Tags: node.js, npm, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am looking to create a simple program that prints the text contents of a pdf file to the screen using the library pdf.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist)

So far, I have an index.js file that is calling `let PDFJS = require('pdfjs-dist');` I installed pdf.js using via the command 'npm i pdfjs-dist'. Problem is, as soon as I tried to run my index.js file 'run index.js' I am hit with the following error

```
/path/to/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:1361
       await this._transport?.destroy();
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

I'd like to know if anyone else had faced a similar issue when using pdf.js (will provide link) and if so, how to fix it? is there something that I require before using pdf.js?

any help would be very helpful.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: the version is v12.20.0

Comment: That's pretty ancient, v12 will be EOL next month. Time to update